# Is this semaphore implementation faulty?

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

In my current assignment, we are to use a Semaphore to synchronize access to critical sections. However, the provided implementation has me questioning whether it is properly implemented or not. I'd like someone to confirm my worries.

```
public class Semaphore {
    private int iValue;

    public Semaphore(int piValue) {
        this.iValue = piValue;
    }

    public Semaphore() {
        this(0);
    }

    public synchronized boolean isLocked() {
        return (this.iValue <= 0);
    }

    public synchronized void P() {
        try {
            while(this.iValue <= 0) {
                wait();
            }

            this.iValue--;
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void V() {
        ++this.iValue;
        notifyAll();
    }
}
```

I believe that there is a possibility for deadlock in this code:

1. Thread A calls `P()` and `iValue` is decremented to 0.
2. Thread B calls `P()` before thread A can call `V()`. The value of `iValue` is 0, so it enters the while loop.
3. Thread A now tries to call `V()`, but cannot because thread B holds the lock. Therefore, there is a deadlock.

Is my conclusion correct?

Comment: If this was true, how could you ever use `wait`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

When you `wait` the lock is released (you get it back when the wait is over).

[Javadoc for wait](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait%28%29):

> The current thread must own this object's monitor. The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method. The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and resumes execution.